# Git bash here only on folder hover

Tags: git, git-bash

When i click once on folder (highlight it) I can choose from context menu Git Bash Here and Git GUI Here. I cannot do this, however, when I enter folder and right-click on empty space in that folder. I used to do both. After format and reinstall git extensions I do not have both options now. What might be the cause of that?

**I always install git extensions which includes git and choose Simple Context Menu when installing GIT after format.**

Answer (score 0):

The key that controls this is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/41880812e/windows.ps1#L51-L54)

Comment: Yes, and apparently I have those in place, how can I enable them however?